# How to install the latest version of terminator?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, repository, launchpad, terminator

If I follow the steps of [gnometerminator.blogspot.de](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.de/p/introduction.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-terminator
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

then I end up having `terminator` version 0.98, but according to the [terminator launchpad site](https://launchpad.net/terminator/gtk3/1.91) there is already version 1.91

Whats wrong here? Thank you in advance

Comment: this repo (ppa:gnome-terminator) works for me on 20.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 6):

You can download the tar file here :

```
https://launchpad.net/terminator/gtk3/1.91/+download/terminator-1.91.tar.gz
```

After that you can :

```
#tar xzvf   terminator-1.91.tar.gz
#cd  terminator-1.91
#cp ./data/terminator.appdata.xml.in ./data/terminator.appdata.xml
#cp ./data/terminator.desktop.in ./data/terminator.desktop
# ./setup.py install
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but they are writing on their page NOT to download it directly, cause its more secure to use `apt`. I was just wondering because of the huge version difference 0.98 and 1.91, but anyway I will just go with the version from the website.

Comment: And how to uninstall this again?

Comment: sudo apt-get --purge remove terminator

Comment: I had to install psutil: `pip install --user psutil`

Answer (score 6):

The method described here worked for me... http://www.webupd8.org/2017/02/terminal-emulator-terminator-sees-new.html

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-terminator/nightly-gtk3
sudo apt update
sudo apt install terminator python-cairo
```

Comment: this method not working anymore. did you know the new ppa?

Comment: on 20.04.2 LTS errors: 
"Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~gnome-terminator/ubuntu/nightly-gtk3'.
The team named '~gnome-terminator' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/nightly-gtk3'
Please choose from the following available PPAs:
 * 'ppa':  PPA for Terminator"

Answer (score 5):

There is a new ppa maintained with the latest version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mattrose/terminator
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

Also, the project now lives on [gnome-terminator/terminator](https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator).

Comment: Awesome. Is there any option to deactivate the middle mouse button paste?

Comment: Guess not. You can try running xinput set-button-map <id> 1 0 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, where id is the id of your mouse, which you can find with xinput list | grep 'id='  

The  location of the 0 is the middle button,  which I turned of by setting it to 0. You can get the  button map by running  xinput get-button-map <id>

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. :)